# ehcache 2.8.5 seems hold 1 million entries at most

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

recently, we opened a production server's ehcache jmx interface, and start a continuous monitor.

when monitoring, we find that a small object's cache seems has a ceiling capacity, which is like 1 million.

this is the monitor graph, that has a ceiling amount. the graph's y-axis is ObjectCount in cache, which is get through ehcache jmx interface.

[graph ehcache object count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1gRx.png)

our cache setting is like this:

```
<cache name="prodStockApiEhCache" maxBytesLocalHeap="200M" overflowToDisk="false" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="240" timeToLiveSeconds="360" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

there is no specified configuration at cachemanager level.

our cached class is like :

```
public class ProductStock {

    private long productId;

    private int productCount;

    private int pickingCount;

    private int lackType;

    private int areaSale;

    //getter and setter....
}
```

we reseached ehcache's object size estimation method, it use google's sizeof-agent.jar.

we test with sizeof-agent.jar. our class's instance heap size is about 40 Bytes. if we mutiply 1 million, it equals 40M, which is much less than 200M that we configured.

also, we seached ehcache(2.8.5)'s source, and did not find any 1 million limitation. also, we checked our ehcachemanager instance's configuration at eclipse debug model, the maxEntriesOnHeap is 0, which means no limitation.

this is wired, is there any infomation we missed? is the monitoring graph's connotation right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no 1 000 000 entries limitation that I am aware of. Can you provide the the full `ehcache.xml`?

Have you looked that the JMX stats? Is there any eviction?

Comment: Thanks Henri. we test other "maxBytesLocalHeap" value in a small test project. the result is like: when  maxBytesLocalHeap=100M, we can cache 729 thousand objects; when  maxBytesLocalHeap=200M, we can cache 1.39 million objects; when maxBytesLocalHeap=300M,  we can cache 1.456 million objects.  this test prove there is no 1 million entries limitation in another way.   may be Ehcache calculates not only cached objects local heap bytes. may be there are other objects need to be included in.